# Basic REST insert operation in Openshift via Node.js into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, openshift

I want to implement an `INSERT` operation with `node.js` in `Openshift`. But it does not work. This is what I received. `http://nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com/UserSetting/firstName="Smith"&lastName="Mr"`

[image]
[image]

I haven't found anything in the log files.

Some indifferent lines:

```
[nodejs-j4nos.rhcloud.com 5556b4c4fcf9336abf0000de]\> tail app-root/logs/nodejs.log 
DEBUG: Sending SIGTERM to child...
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program 'server.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/5556b4c4fcf9336abf0000de/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/5556b4c4fcf9336abf0000de/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.
Express server listening on port 8080
```

Here is my magic code, I have set up mongodb in web interface. Password / credentials is able to see. Just for fun because I was not sure I (re)installed express, mongoose module via `npm`. BTW it is required to install them or it is automatic?

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');

var connection_string = '127.0.0.1:27017/YOUR_APP_NAME';
// if OPENSHIFT env variables are present, use the available connection info:
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
    connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
    process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
}

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// the client db connection scope is wrapped in a callback:
var _db;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://'+connection_string, function(err, db) {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    _db = db
                    })

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function(){
                              console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
                              });

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!');
        });

app.post('/:collection', function(req, res) { //A
         var database = req.params.database;
         var collection = req.params.collection;
         var object = req.body;

         _db.save(collection, object, function(err,docs) {
                               if (err) { res.send(400, err); }
                               else { res.send(201, docs); } //B
                               });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

openshift in mongodb doesn't support sharding,

probably is a good idea to try mongolab that also have a free plan and you will be better prepared to scale https://mongolab.com/

and is really easy to configure in nodejs, you just put the hostname, port, username and password and it just works

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all check authentication with database.

2) Without authentication insert (or any) operation is not performed.

```
if (db.authenticate(mongoUser, mongoPassword.toCharArray()) == false) {
    System.out.println("Failed to authenticate DB ");
}
```